# What is a Hulten potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, neutrons

What is the Hulten potential? (also spelled Hulthén, Hulthen, and Hultén.) When is it used?  How is it derived?

I vaguely heard about in the context of neutron synthesis / quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This potential is explained at https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Hulthen_potential.

According to this it's a model of potential which behaves similar to Coulomb potential.

$$V(r)=-\frac{Z}{\alpha}\frac{\exp(-r/\alpha)}{1-\exp(-r/\alpha)}$$

I don't know how it's derived, but it was derived by a German dude.

This paper compares both the Coulomb Potential and Hulthen potential:

> On the Coulomb and Hulthén Potentials. ST Ma. [*Aust. J. Phys.* **7**, 365 (1954)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1071/PH540365), [ADS eprint](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1954AuJPh...7..365M).

Worth a read and may help with the answers to your questions.